# Converting data types of Foreign Keys to use Joiner in Google Cloud Data Fusion Pipeline

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion, cdap

I am building a pipeline that connects to an on-prem Oracle DB using the Database Plugin, queries two tables (`table_a`, `table_b`), and joins those tables using Joiner Plugin, before uploading to a BigQuery table.

The problem I have now is that the Foreign Keys to join `table_a` and `table_b` have different data types when I use `Get Schema` in the Database Plugin. In Joiner, I am joining the tables on `table_a.customer_id = table_b.customer_id`.

The dtype of `table_a.customer_id` is `LONG` but `table_b.customer_id` is `DOUBLE`. In the source Oracle DB, both columns are actually integers. For some reason, though, using `Get Schema` thinks they are `LONG` and `DOUBLE`.

I am obviously getting an error in Joiner trying to join on a foreign keys with different data types.

Is there a way to cast/convert the columns from the tables to match so that I can use Joiner?

I've seen some examples using Wrangler Transform to parse dates, but I don't see anything to convert to any other data types. I couldn't find any directive examples either: https://github.com/data-integrations/wrangler.

[image: pipeline]

Comment: Can you take a look for this [documentation](https://stephanefrechette.dev/posts/join-group-by-and-aggregate-in-cloud-data-fusion/)?

Comment: I have looked through that before and it doesn't mention anything about how to deal with joining two dates sources on keys of different data types

Comment: I found [Set type](https://github.com/data-integrations/wrangler/blob/release/4.1/wrangler-docs/directives/set-type.md) directive, which convert data type (including LONG and DOUBLE)

Answer (score 1):

You can transform your data before joining them by using any of the transform plugins that Cloud Data Fusion offers. As @muscat mentioned, you can use Wrangler transform and utilize the [Set type](https://github.com/data-integrations/wrangler/blob/release/4.1/wrangler-docs/directives/set-type.md) directives, or you can use the Projection transform and configure the Convert field.